# Excel VBA Match if value is null

Tags: vba, excel

I have a piece of code within a larger script that simply allocates a value to "i" based on a match. The idea being I want it to give the match value if the value entered is found, or 0 if not. If it's 0, I can then exit sub with a message to the user. However, any time the match finds a null value, it just kills the sub, instead of it being handled as part of the iferror I've introduced. I've tried various manners of checking (using iif(iserror) for example) but none seem to work.

Code causing the issue is below:

```
i = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(username, EL.Range("A:A"), 0), 0)
```

i is dim as an integer

Username is dim as a string, and comes from an inputbox

EL is dim as a worksheet, and contains the correct info.

This has absolutely no issues if I introduce any name that exists, it only fails as soon as I input a name that does not work, and I'm sort of stumped as to why. I see no reason for it to fail, but feel like I'm missing something simply and in-my-face.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this instead. Using Application instead of WorksheetFunction enables the error to be trapped and tested.

```
i = Application.IfError(Application.Match(UserName, EL.Range("A:A"), 0), 0)
```

Comment: I'm officially an idiot. Instantly resolved the issue, thanks very much.

Comment: @JayC if SJR answer helped you, then you should accept it as "ANSWER", click on the gray check-mark on the left side of his answer, and it will trun green

Comment: I was intending to, unfortunately it slipped my mind as you can't accept an answer within the first 15 minutes of raising a query. Cheers for the reminder

Answer (score 3):

I would use a slightly different approach to trap an error on `Application.Match` function:

```
Dim i As Variant

i = Application.Match(UserName, EL.Range("A:A"), 0)
' if Match wasn't able to found a "match"
If IsError(i) Then i = 0
```